# YQL - description: undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, yql

```
 var YQL = require('yql');
 var site = "http://words.hk/zidin/v/10853/%E4%BF%BE/%E7%95%80";
 var path = ="/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/ol/li[1]/div[2]/text()";
YQL.exec('select * FROM htmlstring WHERE url="'+site+'" AND
xpath="'+path+'"', function(response) { console.log(response); });
```

I'm trying to obtain the element which has the definition of a character. I also used this for reference:

```
 https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+*+FROM+htmlstring+WHERE+url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwords.hk%2Fzidin%2Fv%2F10853%2F%25E4%25BF%25BE%2F%25E7%2595%2580'+AND+xpath%3D'%2Fhtml%2Fbody%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Fdiv%5B1%5D%2Fdiv%2Fdiv%5B1%5D%2Ftable%2Ftbody%2Ftr%5B3%5D%2Ftd%5B2%5D%2Fol%2Fli%5B1%5D%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Ftext()'%0A
```

And it worked just the way how I wanted. Now, I wasn't able to get this to work on my server.js file with node. I am getting the following error message when I try to log the response out to console:

```
 { error: { lang:  'en-US', description: undefined } }
```

I've tried to add everything without creating the two variables of **site** and **path** but it still wouldn't be able to produce the same result as I wanted from the developer yahoo reference page I used. Would there be a possible way from YQL to fetch this?

Answer (score 1):

The YQL appears to have some kind of problem in the last few days...
Just check other messages with the tag YQL. This isn't something that we (users) can solve, as is a problem in the Yahoo end.

Only solution for now is wait some fix from the Yahoo side...